# How to correctly send JSON string from PHP and parse it in Java to get POJO?

Tags: java, php, android, json, jsonexception

I am using `json_encode` to create JSON string in PHP. `$result` is my SQL result.

```
        $final_op="";
        if(empty($result) == false){

            $rows = array();
            while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $rows[] = $r;
            }
            $final_op=json_encode($rows);
        }
```

when I get this json string at the client end I get it like

```
 [{"username":"vikasdevde","user_fname":"Vikas Devde","user_work":"Programmer"}]
```

And I am parsing it in Java as below

```
                 try{

                        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String aJsonUsername = jObject.getString("username");
                        String aJsonFname = jObject.getString("user_fname");
                        String aJsonUserWork = jObject.getString("user_work");

                  }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println("JSON Exception");
                    }
```

But I'm getting a JSONException, may be it is because of the square brackets around, because after some research I tried with hard-coded string

```
  "{\"username\":\"vikasdevde\",\"user_fname\":\"Vikas Devde\",\"user_work\":\"Programmer\"}"
```

and it worked. Could you please let me know what should be the best way to handle this?

Comment: I don't know how to read this in java, but you are sending an array. You have to parse it as so in JAVA. Edit: in your code, you seem to be trying to read it only as a simple object, not an array os objects.

Comment: Is it expected that you will always get exactly one row from the result set?

Comment: @FirstOne yes that is what I'm asking here, it is being sent as array, and I'm looking for best way to handle this.

Comment: You should use a JSONArray to iterate over top-level items and fetch every array item as JSONObject.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul For this instance I'm getting only one row in the result, but if you could also provide some info on how it is done with multiple that might help me or anyone else reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
    String username= jsonobject.getString("username");
    String user_fname= jsonobject.getString("user_fname");
    String user_work= jsonobject.getString("user_work");
}
```

That is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
json_encode($rows, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

For more reference, check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your java code like this

```
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(response);
JSONObject jObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String aJsonUsername = jObject.getString("username");
String aJsonFname = jObject.getString("user_fname");
String aJsonUserWork = jObject.getString("user_work");
```

replace code in your try block with this